# Command to remove all files and folders recursively including, hidden ones, on MAC OS Terminal?

Tags: macos, rm

`rm -rf *` will remove all files and folders but not hidden ones.

`rm -rf .*` will remove all hidden files and folders, but not those that are not hidden, correct?

What command should one type, in order to delete all files and folders including the hidden ones? (except . and ..); ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
rm -rf * .*
```

will do the trick.

Comment: NO!  `.*` will expand to all invisible entries in the current directory *including* `..` -- which means that using `.*` as an argument to `rm -rf` will attempt to *delete the directory above the one you're currently in, and all of its contents*.  rm will refuse to do it, but I don't consider relying on this safe...

Comment: @Gordon Davisson: I've created a directory. I've added files to it, including hidden files. I've make that command. It has deleted all the contents inside that directory recursively, and it haven't deleted any content ABOVE that directory. Can you please clarify your comment ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on your comment above. Now I understand your point. Any alternative suggestion then ?

Comment: how about using `find` with the `-delete` flag...

Comment: @GordonDavisson `rm` should print a `rm: "." and ".." may not be removed` message in that case – it'll not automatically remove the parent directory.

Comment: @slhck: right, it's the "should" that makes me nervous.  It's a bit like saying "the gun's safety *should* keep it from shooting my foot off when I do this..."

Comment: @GordonDavisson Well, it *does* print the message on OS X, I don't know about GNU though and of course you're right. Better be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -delete
```

I'm not certain that `-mindepth` is supported by all implementations of `find`; if yours doesn't have it, `-path` should give another way to keep it from trying to delete `.`:

```
find . -path "*/*" -delete
```

Comment: BSD `find` has that option too, yup.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this command to purge files/directories according to specific criteria:

```
# tmpwatch -fauv 0 .
```

Answer (score 0):

`shopt -s dotglob` also makes `*` include files that start with a period.